# Docker container doesn't respond to requests

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I have .net backend in docker container with port -p 5001:5001
I make localhost curl request and have "curl: (52) Empty reply from server "

But without docker backend work correct with same port.

My dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-bionic AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5001
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS publish
WORKDIR /
COPY  ./ ./
WORKDIR /Somedir
RUN dotnet publish "Somedir.csproj" -c Debug -o /app/publish
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Somedir.dll"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, your .NET api in the container is actually listening on port 80 and 443. The launchsettings don't actually change the startup for the container. Try changing your port to -p 5001:443

Comment: Thanks! But why docker showed me in "docker ps" 5001:5001?

Comment: The easy answer is: You told it to. When you started your container with -p 5001:5001, docker started your container with those ports linked. So docker ps repeated back to you exactly what you asked it to do. I think this is a great case of human vs machine, where the person had an intent, and the machine obeyed exactly what you told it to do instead lol

Comment: So in that case i can change listening port only in program parameters? Not in docker?

Comment: Yes and no. The listening port for your program can only be changed in your program. The listening port for your container is set in docker. Think of docker as being its own computer, with the ability to port forward. When docker receives information into port 5001, the left entry, you have to tell it where to go, which is 443, the right entry. So you can tell docker to forward that wherever you want, but your program is only listening to 80 and 443.